# Explaining AMPscript "MOD" function

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I found this wonderful piece of ampscript from Adam Spriggs https://gist.github.com/wvpv/478db63dd8b1b0d22b47a4222152226f, and wanted to experiment / test it out to understand it.

```
%%[

var @day, @suffix

 set @day = Format(Now(),"dd"))
  set @Outputday = Format(Now(),"dd"))

for @day = 1 to 31 do

  /* adapted from http://stackoverflow.com/a/13627586/812377 */
  if mod(@day,10) == 1 and mod(@day,100) != 11 then
    set @suffix = "st"
  elseif mod(@day,10) == 2 and mod(@day,100) != 12 then
    set @suffix = "nd"
  elseif mod(@day,10) == 3 and mod(@day,100) != 13 then
    set @suffix = "rd"
  else
    set @suffix = "th"
  endif

  outputline(concat("<br>",@day,@suffix))

next @i

]%%
<br><br>
%%=v(@Outputday)=%%
<br><br>
%%=Mod(@Outputday, 05)=%%
```

Focal points here is the output day. For instance, today, on the 15th, it outputs 15. However, what i do not get is the MOD function.

The documentation explains: *This function returns the remainder after dividing the first number by the second number.*

I've tried three scenarios:

- %%=Mod(@Outputday, 10)=%% (this shows 5, expected 1.5 as 15/10 = 1.5)
- %%=Mod(@Outputday, 5)=%% (this shows 0, expected 3 as 15/5 = 3)
- %%=Mod(@Outputday, 05)=%% (this shows 0, expected 3 as 15/05 = 3)

Could someone help explain this to me? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modulo is a core programming concept. It returns the last remaining digit.

> %%=Mod(@Outputday, 10)=%% (this shows 5, expected 1.5 as 15/10 = 1.5)

15/10 - Ten goes in 15 1, remainder 5.

> %=Mod(@Outputday, 5)=%% (this shows 0, expected 3 as 15/5 = 3)

15/5 - 5 goes in 15 3 times , 0 remainder hence 0 sam with the 3 case

With a value of 25,

%%=Mod(25,10)=%% will still give 5.

For more information please check out the following links:

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)

[Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/e/modulo-operator)

or searching the main stack overflow forum

Comment: Thanks Data Kid ! :) Is my understanding correct if MOD(28,12) would give 4?
and MOD(52,12) would also give 4? (so it divides, and returns remainders that cannot be divided?)

Comment: You sir are 100% correct :)